# Uninstall a package & getting a long list

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, software-uninstall

Greetings Linux experts;
I'm learning Ubuntu Linux for 2 months now and I'm really enjoying it. I'm trying to keep learning the terminal's commands and this is what I'm getting on the screen when uninstalling a package.
I'm running the command: "**sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pdfsam**" for total deletion of the system. I ran this command twice to make sure it is done. The second time I ran the command I'm getting a long list of packages which I will paste bellow. I would like to know if these packages are install on the system, if just are files that can be removed or what?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pdfsam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'pdfsam' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386* gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly* java-wrappers* kde-l10n-engb*
  libapache-pom-java* libasound2:i386* libaudio2:i386* libavahi-client3:iz386*
  libavahi-common-data:i386* libavahi-common3:i386* libbcmail-java*
  libbcpkix-java* libbcprov-java* libcommons-codec-java*
  libcommons-httpclient-java* libcommons-logging-java* libcommons-parent-java*
  libcups2:i386* libdom4j-java* libdrm-amdgpu1:i386* libdrm-intel1:i386*
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386* libdrm-radeon1:i386* libechonest2.1* libedit2:i386*
  libelf1:i386* libexpat1:i386* libffi6:i386* libfontconfig1:i386*
  libfreetype6:i386* libftgl2* libgcrypt11:i386*
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily:i386* libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386*
  libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386* libglib2.0-0:i386* libgnuinet-java*
  libgnumail-java* libgnutls26:i386* libgpg-error0:i386*
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386* libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386*
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386* libice6:i386* libitext-java* libjaxen-java*
  libjbig0:i386* libjdom1-java* libjgoodies-common-java*
  libjgoodies-looks-java* libjpeg-turbo8:i386* libjpeg8:i386*
  libk5crypto3:i386* libkeyutils1:i386* libkrb5-3:i386*
  libkrb5support0:i386*
  liblastfm1* liblinear-tools* liblinear1* libllvm3.6:i386* liblog4j1.2-java*
  liblouis-data* liblouis2* libmysqlclient18:i386* liborc-0.4-0:i386*
  libp11-kit0:i386* libpciaccess0:i386* libprojectm2* libqt4-declarative:i386*
  libqt4-network:i386* libqt4-opengl:i386* libqt4-script:i386*
  libqt4-sql:i386* libqt4-sql-mysql:i386* libqt4-xml:i386*
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386* libqtcore4:i386* libqtdbus4:i386*   
  libqtgui4:i386*
  libqtwebkit-qmlwebkitplugin:i386* libqtwebkit4:i386* libqxt-core0*
  libqxt-gui0* libsm6:i386* libsqlite3-0:i386* libstdc++6:i386*
  libtasn1-6:i386* libtiff5:i386* libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386* libx11-6:i386*
  libx11-xcb1:i386* libxau6:i386* libxcb-dri2-0:i386* libxcb-dri3-0:i386*
  libxcb-glx0:i386* libxcb-present0:i386* libxcb-sync1:i386* libxcb1:i386*
  libxdamage1:i386* libxdmcp6:i386* libxerces2-java* libxext6:i386*
  libxfixes3:i386* libxi6:i386* libxml-commons-external-java*
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java* libxml2:i386* libxom-java* libxpp2-java*
  libxpp3-java* libxrender1:i386* libxshmfence1:i386* libxslt1.1:i386*
  libxt6:i386* libxxf86vm1:i386* mysql-common* nymgo-bin:i386* projectm-data*
  python3-brlapi* python3-louis* python3-pyatspi* python3-speechd*
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 122 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 After this operation, 199 MB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Autoremove & Purge

```
apt-get autoremove
```

will remove all old packages that are no longer needed.

```
apt-get purge
```

Will removes a specific package install. When running

```
apt-get autoremove --purge package
```

you are telling the system to remove old pakages then uninstall package. It is completely safe to execute the command as written.